# Root composer.json requires square/module-squareup-omni, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

Tags: magento2.4

Im using Square Payments from magento marketplace,

While using  **composer require square/module-squareup-omni:1.15.0**

getting below error:
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires square/module-squareup-omni, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Anyone please help me.

Magento2.4.5